# Twitter followers by location

Tags: json, twitter, get

Let's say we have a business like Coca-Cola: https://twitter.com/cocacola.
Given the Twitter API, how would you find all **followers** of Coca-Cola who live in **New York**?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAkG53XRg2s

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the [official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list).

You can get a list of all the followers (200 at a time) using

```
    https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=CocaCola&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=true
```

You will receive a list of users. You can use the Location or TimeZone property to *estimate* location.

Remember, users can lie about where they are.

Comment: Does one need OAuth? A GET request of the URL returns a JSON response from Twitter with a 215 error.

Comment: All requests to Twitter require a signed request. But, You don't need to be, say, CocaCola in order to see their followers.